# git add files that contain X

Tags: git

In git, how can you add all files to the next commit whose diffs contain a specified string?

I'm looking for something like: `git add search('changes')`.

Comment: Diffs? Is it okay to just add the files that contain that string? (Would it even make a difference? :D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `grep -Rl` (recursive grep, listing files with matches) and `xargs` (pass list of files as arguments to another program).

Comment: I think @Balthamos provides a better answer to this question -- it includes actual examples and matches files where the *diff* contains the string, instead of all files the just contain the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
git diff -S "regex" --name-only | xargs git add
```

Take note that the command above will add *all* changes in a matching file. If you want more control which hunks get added, I highly recommend using `git add -p` (not just for this scenario, but all the time).

If you want to reduce the files you want to look at, you can combine it with the first command mentioned.

```
git diff -S "regex" --name-only | xargs git add -p
```